# Shared viewModel achived fragment lifecycle

Tags: android, viewmodel, android-architecture-components

How I can use shared viewModel with fragments without activity?
Like in code but in place of requireActivity() use ParentFragment. In this case when ParentFragment will destroyed, SharedViewModel is cleared, but when I provide SharedViewModel from activity, it not cleared when ParentFragment destroyed.

And I use Navigation Components, which mean that I can`t set tag for fragment and then use findFragmentByTag()

```
class ParentFragment:Fragment{

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
      var viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(requireActivity()).get(SharedViewModel::class)
    }
}

class ChildFragment:Fragmnet{
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
      var viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(requireActivity()).get(SharedViewModel::class)
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `parentFragment` in place of `requireActivity()` in `ChildFragment` class?

Comment: @djhs16 No, i don`t know how to access to ```ParentFragment``` from ```ChildFragment```. I dont know how to find ```ParentFragment``` in ```FragmentManager```

Comment: Have you tried `fragment.getParentFragment()`?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce  ```ParentFragment``` is wrong. Because it is fragment that contains current fragment, non previously from which is current add to fragment manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [scoped-vm](https://github.com/dhabensky/scoped-vm) - it allows you to request ViewModel for *scope* identified by a String key. Scope lives till the last fragment that requested ViewModel gets destroyed, then ViewModel gets cleared.

You can use this code to obtain SharedViewModel both in ParentFragment and ChildFragment.

```
ScopedViewModelProviders
     .forScope(this, "scope")
     .of(requireActivity())
     .get(SharedViewModel::class.java)
```

Comment: Yeah, it`s exact that need. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See you can initialize viewModel in all fragments which you want to share viewmodel, and use Rx with viewModel, your all process in these fragments will keep running until you want to cancel it,you can call viewModel.oncleard() from Activity or Fragment.

```
public override fun onCleared() {
super.onCleared()
compositeDisposable.dispose()
// or cancel any process
}
```

[If you do not know ViewModel Scope, please check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/747F2.png)